# Blackberry: setTitle with image displays a black border in os 5.0

Tags: blackberry

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(stage+"-whatson-header_"+reslabel+".png");
    BitmapField title = new BitmapField();
    title.setBitmap(image);
    setTitle(title);
```

In os 5.0, below the image is a black line or border, and I have no idea what is causing it. I made sure my image does not have any transparency that may be causing a glitch.

Comment: The same is happening to me using a tiled background being paint from a "CustomTitleField extends Field". I get a black 4px gap between the title and the Manager in the MainScreen.

Comment: is there any solution to remove the black line ?